# I'm trying to do uploading data to database using ajax Django,But it does't work properly

Tags: django, ajax

I'm a beginner in Django. I have to upload data to the database using ajax. For that, I'm trying some code but it doesn't work properly. I can't upload data using these codes. Is this right way of ajax coding

**requirement:**
actual need is in my Django app, upon viewing the contact details of the product, a notification should be sent to the user. For that I trying this method. I don't know is this working method

models.py

```
class Notifications(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, 
    null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notification = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str_(self):
    return self.notification
```

views.py

```
def notification(request):
    user = request.user 
    if request.method == 'POST':
       property_id = request.POST['property_id'] 
       owner = request.POST['owner_id']
       property_object = 
       Property.objects.get(id=property_id)
       owner_object = User.objects.all().get(username=owner)
       notification =  user, "have intrested in your property", property_object.headline 
       property_object.notify.add(user)
       notifications = Notifications.objects.create(notification=notification, property=property_object, owner=owner_object)

       notifications.save()

       return JsonResponse({'msg':'success'})
```

ajax

```
<form action="{% url 'like_post'  %}" method="post" id="notify_form" >
                {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="hidden" name="owner_id" value="{{ accomodation.owner }}">
            <button id="request-btn" name="property_id" value="{{ accomodation.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Contact info:</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">` 
$(document).ready(function(e){
$(document).on('submit','#request-btn',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"{% url 'notification' %}",
        data:$('#notify_form').serialize(),
        dataType:'Json',
        success:function(data){
            if(data,msg == "success"){
                alert('data submitted')
            }
        }

    });
  });
});
```

`

Comment: is there any error occures in console in browser's inspect

Comment: Hello sir, do you have a method Create in Notifications model? If you don't that "Notifications.objects.create(...)" will return a error

Comment: hi, Luiz, my requirement is in my Django app, upon viewing the contact details of the product, a notification should be sent to the user. For that I trying the above method. I don't know is this working method